# Loading the resource identified by a script element's src attribute

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a function to load the resource identified by a `<script>` element's `src` attribute.

I need it to:

- Be as universal as possible.
- Work on file-to-file requests (from `file://` to `file://`), if the browser allows to.

This is the code I have so far:

```
var asyncGetContents = function(node,listener){
   var hasRun = false;
   if(node.src){
      var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
      httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function() {
         if(httpRequest.responseText){
            if(hasRun){return;}
            hasRun = true;
            listener(httpRequest.responseText);
            httpRequest.onreadystatechange=undefined;
         }
      };
      httpRequest.open('GET', node.src);
      if(node.type){
         httpRequest.overrideMimeType(node.type);
      }
      httpRequest.send();
   }else{
      listener(node.textContent);
   }
};
```

- Is this code well-formed?
- Are there any aspects that I could've possibly missed?
- Is there any way to do it without the variable `hasRun`? Removing the `onReadyStateChange` event listener doesn't seem to work - `listener` function runs twice.

Answer (score 2):

The code looks well-formed. I'd like some comments though and maybe a bit of whitespace here and there.

However, I think there's a good chance this will actually fail. `readystatechange` fires several times during the lifetime of an XHR object. But your code doesn't actually check the XHR object's `readyState`, which is what the event is there to tell you about.

Instead it checks `responseText`, but if the file is large enough to fire several events during its download, `responseText` may only hold partial data. So `responseText` is truthy, and `hasRun` is set to true, but the code won't ever get the complete data.

There's are [5 distinct `readyState` values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest). You should be checking for the `DONE` state only.

Alternatively, for some (most, I believe) browsers [you can simply hook your functions to `onload`, `onerror` and friends](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) instead of of the general `onreadystatechange`.

You may also want to check the arguments: Does `node` exist? Is `listener` a function?

Lastly, how do you handle failures? A 404 will still give you `responseText`, just not anything useful. A simple solution would be something like Node.js's callback pattern, of having the listener receive 2 arguments: `err` and `data`. If `err` is truthy, something went wrong. You also want to simply pass the XHR object along as the 3rd argument, so the `listener` can make whatever checks it wants to (much like jQuery does).

```
function asyncGetContents(node, listener) {
  var xhr;

  // Example of handling a bad node argument
  // Adapt it to fit your needs
  if(!node) {
    throw new TypeError;
  }

  // Example of handling a bad listener argument
  // Adapt it to fit your needs
  if(typeof listener !== 'function') {
    throw new TypeError;
  }

  if(node.src) {
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
      // check readyState
      if(xhr.readyState === XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
        // check that the response code is 2xx
        if(xhr.status >= 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
          listener(null, xhr.responseText, xhr);
        } else {
          listener(xhr.status, null, xhr); // Provide a more useful error here
        }
      }
    };

    xhr.open('GET', node.src);
    if(node.type) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType(node.type);
    }
    xhr.send();
  } else {
    // we've only checked that node is truthy, not that it's
    // actually a script element, so node.textContent may
    // be `undefined`, but let's leave that to the listener
    listener(null, node.textContent, null);
  }
}
```

Comment: `readyState` is never 4 (the value of `XMLHttpRequest.DONE`) for file-to-file requests (from `file://` to `file://`). Also `status` is allways 0.

Comment: @m93a Ah, right. I'd advice you to check the URL to handle that special case - `if(/^file:/.test(node.src)) { ... }`

Comment: @m93a Chill. Take my advice or leave it. For relative paths, if the script src url doesn't have a http/https/file scheme (though most browsers will resolve `node.src` to a full URL if it's relative), check `window.location` instead.